# Shifting data from all even number rows in dataframe to its previous row

Tags: python, dataframe, rows, shift

An example dataframe is as follows:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 222 | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | A1 | AA55 | NaN |
| BB | 555 | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | B1 | BB44 | NaN |

From here, basically the correct full data would be that row 2 is the missing parts of row 1 and row 4 is the missing parts of row 3, and this repeats to all the dataframe (around  5 million rows)

The filling though is not so easy, for example:

- Column B and row 2 value "A1" would be the column C row 1 value.
- Column C and row 2 value "AA55" would be the column D row 1 value.
- The extra values (NaN) in the even number rows (rows 2 and 4 in the example) are discarded.

The resulting dataframe would be like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 222 | A1 | AA55 |
| BB | 555 | B1 | BB44 |

Basically it's a shifting of even number rows 1 place up and 1 place right (this is just example, real case the bottom row needs shift and combine with its upper row starting 4 places to the right of its upper row).

I was going to try iterating through the rows (I know it's not efficient but I couldn't think another way) and apply a method I read about ".shift(-1)" which would move a row to the previous place. But I'm not sure how to apply it here.

Answer (score 0):

If the relative location is always fixed, you could just do shifting:

say if you have:

```
    0   1   2   3
0   1.0 2.0 NaN NaN
1   NaN 3.0 4.0 NaN
2   5.0 6.0 NaN NaN
3   NaN 7.0 8.0 NaN
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2., np.nan, np.nan],
                   [np.nan, 3, 4, np.nan],
                   [5, 6, np.nan, np.nan],
                   [np.nan, 7, 8, np.nan]])
df.iloc[::2, 2:] = df.values[1::2, 1:3]
df.iloc[::2]
```

```
    0   1   2   3
0   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
2   5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0
```

Comment: Thank you! This did not solve my problem but it did give me a hint on how to. Using iloc[::2] I separated my dataframe into two, one with even rows and the other one with odd rows. So now I have two dataframes with same length and row 1 of df2 is the complement of row 1 of df1, and the same with all the following rows so I just had to replace the corresponding columns ones by one.